# Can you prove the possibility to rewrite any lorentz invariant equation as the component of a 4-tensor?

Tags: special-relativity, classical-mechanics, symmetry

When studying special relativity, there is usually a point where 4-tensors get introduced. Since all of physics equations are supposed to be lorentz-invariant, it is assumed that these equations are all 4-tensor equations i.e. relations between tensor components.

Can this be proven in any way? Is there a general procedure to show that you can write a tensor equation out of any physical equation?

Comment: I wouldn't call it a relation between tensor components; rather, a relation between geometric objects (tensors) that can be expressed not just in tensor notion, but in a coordinate-free manner.

Answer (score 0):

> Can this be proven in any way?

Yes, physics is independent of the coordinates in the sense that the mathematical operation of changing your coordinates does not change any of the physical outcomes of any experiment. Therefore any physical experiment **can** be represented with a coordinate independent expression.

> Is there a general procedure to show that you can write a tensor equation out of any physical equation?

I think that you have this backwards. You can start with a physical tensor equation, and produce non-tensor expressions. If some of those expressions involve approximations or assumptions then the resulting equations may not be able to go back into a tensor expression. The fact that the general laws can be written as tensors doesn't apply that a given specific law can.

One example is circuit theory. Circuit theory is a non-relativistic simplification of Maxwell's equations. You can go from the tensor-form of Maxwell's equations to circuit theory with some appropriate approximations, but you cannot go back to a tensor-based circuit theory.

Comment: According to special relativity, true physical equations are lorentz-invariant. I wanted to know whether all lorentz-invariant equations could be written as tensor equations. Approximations excluded